# Facebook Payment Verify Token

Tags: php, facebook, token, verify, real-time-updates

I've tried to understand facebook's tutorials on this but it's as if those things were written by monkeys or something.  I have no idea how to do this via their explanations....

I am setting up realtime updates and keep getting back the wrong or no response at all with the verify token test.

```
Object: payments

Fields: actions, disputes

Callback: PATH_TO_MY_CALLBACK_URL

Verify token: tokentest
```

And then in the callback.php page, i have this...

```
<?php 
$verify_token = "tokentest";
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub.verify_token'] === $verify_token) {
  echo $_GET['hub.challenge'];
}
?>
```

And my response after the test is this....

```
Response does not match challenge, expected value = '1233944951', received='


'
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok wow... just figured otu what I was doing wrong.  "hub.verify_token" and "hub.challenge" was supposed to be  "hub_verify_token" and "hub_challenge".